# How to delete enclosing braces in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have the following text:

```
Monkeys eat {bananas}.
```

My cursor is in the middle of the word `banana`:

```
Monkeys eat {bana|nas}.
```

Here the `|` symbol denotes the cursor's position.

How can I delete the braces from there?

I can change `bananas` to `apples` with a simple `ci}apples`, so perhaps I could use a similar trick just to get rid of the `{` and `}` characters?

Also, can I do this even in this case, which is actually what I really need to do?

```
networks {
    local
    is|p
}
```

(The simplified example above was just to introduce the concept.)

Comment: Perhaps you could explain, in your "what I really need to do" section, what you would like the *end result* to be. In the answers there seems to be some confusion as to what you really want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The task can be accomplished by means of Vim built-in text motions.
Delete the text inside the braces, select the braces, and paste the
previously deleted text over them:

```
di{v%p
```

Comment: just started properly learning about visual mode as a result of this!  It looks really useful. Thanks

Comment: di{ means delete inside brace. What does v%p mean? Thanks

Comment: @theprogrammer: `v` enters Visual mode; `%` selects from the character under the cursor until (and including) the pairing delimiter (provided that it is `(`, `[`, `{`, etc.); `p` pastes over the selection. (See `:help v`, `:help %`, and `:help p`.)

Answer (score 9):

Using Tim Pope's excellent [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) plugin (which I highly recommend), you would do <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> for *delete surrounding `{`*

I understand that adding another plugin isn't always the ideal solution when you could find a native key sequence instead, but surround.vim is supremely useful, as it can also handle XML/HTML tags and perform enclosures on complex text objects.  I regard it as one of those "stuck on a desert island, must have under any circumstance" plugins.

Comment: I don't like using plug-ins, sorry. Having said that, this is a nice plug-in indeed.

Comment: Plugins may not be your thing, but Tim Pope's plugins are great. I personally cannot get by w/o surround, unimpaired, and commentary. If you ever decide to dip your toe in the wonderful world of plugins, I highly suggest you take a look at some of Tim's plugins. https://github.com/tpope

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
yiBvaBp
```

No plugin and simple.

Comment: Not bad... yank the inner text of a brace (I use } where you use B but that's ok), visually select a brace interval, paste the yank replacing the visual.

Comment: For this particular example, `{banana}`, the fastest is probably `BxE.`

Answer (score 1):

Delete the braces and leave everything else?

```
mz[{x]}x`z
```

### Expanded

`:help m` - set a mark. In this case marking the initial cursor position so I can go back there at the end. `:help [{` - moves the cursor to the opening brace of the smallest block enclosing the cursor. `:help x` - delete the brace which is now under the cursor. `]}` and `x` - doing the same to the closing brace. And finally

```
help `
```

returning to marked position, the one called `z` created at the start.

"Plugins" aren't my style...

Comment: Would probably be appreciated if you could decrypt that for those of us who have no idea what you're doing there.

Comment: m: set mark; z: call it `z`; [{: move to `{`; x: delete character; ]}: move to `}`; x: delete it;  `: return mark; z: to mark called `z`.